# Filter NSMutableArray based on dictionary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

I have array with multiple dictionarys. which contains different keys . here i have goalType each goal contains number of records i want to filter the records based on goalType . please check the format below.

```
 Array==>(  {
         goalType = 1;
         languagetype = 1;
         soundid = 19;
         status = 1;
     },
         {
         goalType = 1;
         languagetype = 1;
         soundid = 20;
         status = 1;
     },
         {
         goalType = 2;
         languagetype = 1;
         soundid = 21;
         status = 1;
     },
         {
         goalType = 2;
         languagetype = 1;
         soundid = 22;
         status = 1;
     },
         {
         goalType = 2;
         languagetype = 1;
         soundid = 23;
         status = 1;
     },
 )
```

i have wrote the below code but filtered array getting empty

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"goalType == %@ && languagetype == %d && status == 1 && soundid <= 3884", 
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:goalType.integerValue],languageid];
 [dataSource predicate];
```

Comment: Why [NSNumber numberWithInt:goalType.integerValue] ? and not [NSNumber numberWithInt:goalType.intValue] or [NSNumber numberWithInteger:goalType.integerValue] ?

Comment: You can try like: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"goalType
 == %d && languagetype == %d && status == 1 && soundid <= 3884", goalType.intValue, languageid];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *theDict = @{@"goalType":@(1),@"languagetype":@(1),@"soundid":@(19),@"status":@(1)};
NSDictionary *theDict1 = @{@"goalType":@(1),@"languagetype":@(1),@"soundid":@(20),@"status":@(1)};
NSDictionary *theDict2 = @{@"goalType":@(2),@"languagetype":@(1),@"soundid":@(21),@"status":@(1)};
NSDictionary *theDict3 = @{@"goalType":@(2),@"languagetype":@(1),@"soundid":@(23),@"status":@(1)};


NSMutableArray *testArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[testArray addObject:theDict];
[testArray addObject:theDict1];
[testArray addObject:theDict2];
[testArray addObject:theDict3];

NSPredicate *predicate =   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"goalType == %@ && languagetype == %@ && status = 1 && soundid <= 3884", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

NSArray *filteredArray = [testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@",filteredArray);
```

This is the code works.

Comment: same result is returning .

Comment: testArray = [testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate1]; assign the filtered array to a new array and nslog

Comment: Try change  languagetype == %d to languagetype == %@,and I tested it, it worked.

Comment: here i am able to predicate with all keys except goalType

Comment: with goal type only returning empty

Comment: here i have goalType as string so i am converting and parsing like

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate =   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"goalType == %@ && languagetype == %@ && status = 1 && soundid <= 3884", [NSNumber numberWithInt:goalType.intValue],[NSNumber numberWithInt:languageid]];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62679/discussion-between-carouselmin-and-boosa-ramesh).

Comment: yea its working with languagetype but i need to predicate with both languagetype and goalType too

Comment: have to be pridicate with all these 4 keys              [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"goalType == %d && languagetype == %@ && status = 1 && soundid <= 3884",[NSNumber numberWithInt:goalType.intValue],languageid]

Answer (score 0):

why not use

```
NSArray's filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
Evaluates a given predicate against each object in the receiving array and returns a new array containing the objects for which the predicate returns true.
```

I don't know of a

```
[NSArray predicate]
```

selector.I'm surprised that your not getting NoMethodFound exception.